# Is it worth migrating from log4j1 to log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We are evolving our corporate Java EE infraestructure and are considering a change in our logging platform. We are currently using **slf4j** as the API and **log4j1** as the underlying logging implementation.

Since we don't directly use log4j's API, but sf4j's, it's all a matter of configuration changes, which have already been done.

Our use of the logging system is pretty basic, so we don't need features like log4j2's advance filtering.

Regarding performance, according to the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html), it doesn't seem to be a huge improvement.

So, do you think we should migrate our apps from slf4j+log4j1 to slf4j+log4j2? Why? What advantages do you think it provides?

Comment: I think you have already noted that the main advantages of log4j2 are not persuasive.  If you want other opinions, read this: http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/07/apache-log4j2

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in switching from log4j to logback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation asynchronuous loggers and appenders seem to improve the performance of Log4J 2 quite drastically: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Performance

Besides: Log4J 1 is End of Life: https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces

From the announcement:

> Apache Log4j 2 features a completely rewritten framework. In addition,
>   it is faster, more reliable, and much easier to develop and maintain.

So, yes, I think it's worth to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 developpers had several brilliant ideas:

- interpret logged data : see CVE-2021-44228. This was a huge scandal.
- make it very, very difficult for the developer to control the loggers, by removing many entry points from the API. We have to directly use the 'core' library to manage a loggers from the code (for instance, the simple thing of setting programmatically the output file of a FileAppender).
- completely change the format of the configuration property files
- provide a fake log4j 1.2 API that relies on a log4j2 implementation but does not implement all former methods, some are now implemented as doing nothing. Consequence: if ever a third party library uses this flawed ersatz API, you can't even use the good old log4j 1.2 in your application, and you might not notice that it doesn't work when you fall into one of the no-op methods.
- if ever you are fool enough to want to control your loggings just a little bit by adding an appender at runtime, you can do that by using the core classes. But these psychopaths will punish you: when you add an appender to a logger... the method also +removes+ all previous appenders created by the configuration file.

I have been using log4j for years and years happily because it was simple and working. Now after some time using the log4j2 s**t I really believe I should switch to something else.

So my answer is: don't migrate to log4j2. Check slf4j for instance.

Comment: Nice answer, I can clearly see your love for log42 :-) Luckily we ended up using logback.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experiance goes, there are no major upgrades with Log4j2 over Log4j. But there are a number of Bug Fixes, raised on Log4j, which have now gone into Log4j2. 
the below link will give info on one such fix

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50213&action=View

Since you are using SLF4j, its very easy to migrate to Log4j2 - there willnot be any code changes, only library changes.